# Getting Error of ViewBag after deploying the Application on Live server Environment( IIS )

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

Application running perfectly on Build in visual Studio server. I publish the project and deployed it on local IIS. Because want to test it how Application behave on Server Environment. But the Application throwing Viewbag Error. The target framework is .Net 4.6.2.

In each view razor (*.cshtml) page:
Added following code your
 `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage And add following line at the top of _ViewStart.cshtml :  @inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage`
[Here is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwtjX.png)

````
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=afsdbserver.database.windows.net;Database=alfa;UID=afsuser;PWD=Twiky123!;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=Ehsan;Database=alfa;integrated security=False;uid=TestLogIn; Password=123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <!--<add name="AlfaFinancialEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/alfaModel.csdl|res://*/alfaModel.ssdl|res://*/alfaModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=alfafin.database.windows.net;initial catalog=alfa;integrated security=False;persist security info=True;user id=alfafin;password=!alfa123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />-->
    <!--<add name="alfaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Ehsan;initial catalog=alfa;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />-->
    <add name="AlfaFinancialEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/alfaModel.csdl|res://*/alfaModel.ssdl|res://*/alfaModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Ehsan;initial catalog=alfa;integrated security=False;uid=TestLogIn; Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="SmtpHost" value="smtp.office365.com"/>
    <add key="SmtpPort" value="587"/>
    <add key="SmtpUser" value="info@alfafinancialsolutions.com"/>
    <add key="SmtpTimeout" value="600000"/>
    <!--this is app Password-->
    <add key="EnableSsl" value="true"/>
    <add key="utcHours" value="5"/>
    <add key="utcMinute" value="30"/>
    <add key="greetingMessage" value="Good Morning,"/>
    <add key="subject" value="Your todays schedule "/>
    <add key="includeAppointmentList" value="true"/>
    <add key="includeTaskList" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="102400" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="65536"/>
    <!--<globalization culture="en-GB"/>-->
    <!--<globalization uiCulture="en-CA" culture="en-CA" />-->
    <sessionState timeout="60"/>
    <!--mintues value-->
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536" />-->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
      <!--mintues value-->
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="1073741824"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib" publicKeyToken="1b03e6acf1164f73" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.2.10" newVersion="1.3.2.10"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.2" newVersion="7.0.0.2"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.0" newVersion="4.0.5.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.21.0.0" newVersion="6.21.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>```



I want to Host this Application On IIS
````

Comment: The error image shows that the application is targeting .net framework 4.0. You may need to change that for the error to go away.

Comment: Please check the IIS logs for any errors or warnings related to the application. Also check web.config file and make sure they are all using the correct host version.